# Having trouble getting ajax to display .php

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to learn Ajax, but keep running into trouble. Basically I'm having the httpRequest check  which browser. Then get the browser to load the .php file into the div.

```
<script>
    function getXMLHTTPRequest(){
        var ajaxRequest = false;

        try{
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e)
        {
            try
            {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e){
                try{
                    new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch(e) {
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        var ajaxRequest = getXMLHTTPRequest();
        ajaxRequest.open("GET","ajaxNewbie.php");

        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {

            if(ajaxRequest.readyState === 4)
            {
                //get the data from the server's response
            document.greetingInfo.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            } else {
            window.alert("readyState = " + ajaxRequest.readyState);
            }
        }       
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="ajaxRequest.send(null);">
    <div id="greetinginfo">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made few errors:

1. getXMLHTTPRequest function is not complete, so it will be called from itself
2. you forgot ajaxRequest.send();

Consider following example:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_get